# Intranet - web to remote wcf CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, authentication, intranet

I have a ASP.NET MVC intranet application hosted in IIS that added WCF service reference the WCF resides in another computer and also expect windows authentication.
In my web this code is working great:

```
proxy = new MyProxyClient("configurationName", "remoteAddress");
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "myUserName";
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "MyPassword";

proxy.SomeMethod(); //work great
```

**but if I want the credential not to be hardcoded like this I am using: CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials like this:**

```
 proxy = new MyProxyClient("configurationName", "remoteAddress");
 proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

 proxy.SomeMethod(); //not working throw exception
```

the above code throw SecurityNegotiationException with message: **The caller was not authenticated by the service.** 
and the inner exception is: **The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.**

How can I pass the credential of the current user to the WCF service without hardcoded user name and password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your organization uses regular Windows authentication (NTLM) you can't do what you want due to "one-hop" restriction: credentials passed from user's computer to your server use "one-hop" (from direct login to one external computer) and such credentials can't be used to authenticate other servers from the first one.

More information can be found using following search term:[ntlm one hop](http://www.bing.com/search?q=ntlm+one+hop),i.e. [Why NTLM fails and Kerberos works](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2010/05/09/double-hop-authentication-why-ntlm-fails-and-kerberos-works.aspx).

Standard solution:

- Kerberos (often requires significant effort to get approval to enable/configure)
- Use some other form of authentication than Windows. Consider if OAuth is possible. Don't go basic auth.
- Switch WCF service to [claims based authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517291.aspx).
- If WCF service can it can trust caller to verify incoming credentials more approaches are possible:

  1. Run code under particular account that signs in locally on server and have permissions to call the service. The easiest approach is what shown in your post, but storing domain passwords (or any passwords) in plain text is not secure. One can also run process account under special credentials that have access to the remote service and temporary revert impersonation after verifying user credentials.
  2. You can also configure WCF service to require client certificate and use such certificate when calling the WCF service. This way WCF service can verify if caller is known.

Answer (score 0):

In the web.config (client and server), in the `<system.serviceModel>` section add/modify a binding to look something like this:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBasicBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

And, add this to client side web.config `<system.web>` section:

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

The two changes will make the end-user the current user of the web request which will then be sent in the WCF message.

The user can then be retrieved on the server side like this:

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity
```

Please make sure the following configuration is there in service web.config.

`<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyWcf.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="MySvcBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyWcf.IService1" bindingConfiguration="MyWsHttpBinding"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyWsHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBasicBinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MySvcBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>`

And in your client configuration file following should be there.

`<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
     <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
       <security>
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
       </security>
      </binding>
     </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
     <endpoint address="http://localhost/MyWcf/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="MyWCFService.IService1"
      name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
     </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>`

I tried by passing `System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` using above configuration and working fine for me. If it's not working for you then put debug point on line which passing credential and watch that `System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` Domain, UserName & Password values are blank or not. If Blank then it should work.

Comment: I made all these configuration but still I dont understand how to pass the current user credentials from the web server to the WCF client proxy... so right now I get the same error...

Comment: Please just make the configuration changes on client and server side web.config and try to create service proxy and call the method. No need to explicitly pass the windows credential. And on server side you can get the windows credential using `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity` Or if possible send me demo app. So, i can help you.

Comment: I am using wsHttpBinding currently... in my configuration I have <security mode="Message"> 
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>       can it be done with this binding?

Comment: in wsHttpBinding I dont have the mode="TransportCredentialOnly" option... what should I choose? or it is impossible to achieve it with wsHttpBinding?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please read it carefully and apply the same configuration.

Comment: I tried it exactly and it doesnt work but I find something interesting: If I use visual studio development server it is working but whe using iis the remote call not working.

Comment: @ilayzeidman - you can't workaround one-hop restriction this way as incoming user's credentials can't be used outside the server. I've added answer with standard solutions.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that if you're looking within your `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` attribut you won't see the credential information.
From Microsoft website : The authentication informations return by the DefaultNetworkCredentials property will be only available for NTLM, Negotiate or Kerberos authentication.

To get your credential you need to implement this authentication.

You can use it by using impersonation wihtin your intranet application.
Impersonation allow your intranet application to be executed by the user of this one.

More information here :http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961980.aspx

Comment: but when you use WCF it is not NTLM or Negotiate or Kerberos? I dont want to implement my own security I want to get the current register user credentials in my web and pass it to the WCF client proxy

Comment: In IIS, you have defined an authentication for your intranet web application such NTLM, KERBEROS, Anonymous... to keep the informations from your user through your webservices WCF, you need to use impersonation

Comment: can you write code how do I pass the credentials to the WCF client proxy?