# Getting DefaultNetworkCredentials to pass through to WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, wcf

I have a WCF service I have created in a WebApplication with the following configuration in web.config

```
<service name="RedwebServerManager.WebApplication.DesktopService"
           behaviorConfiguration="ServBehave">
    <endpoint
       address=""
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="basicBind"
        contract="RedwebServerManager.WebApplication.IDesktopService"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicBind">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

This service needs to take in WindowsCredentials in to get information in a database based upon the authenticated user. This service current has one method implementing an interface with the following signature

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface IDesktopService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the clients.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>IEnumerable&lt;ClientServiceModel&gt;.</returns>
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<ClientServiceModel> GetClients();
}
```

I have a Windows Forms application which is consuming the WCF service and I want to pass through the credentials of the current user using the application as this will all be sitting on our domain. The app.config is as follows

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDesktopService">
              <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"/>
              </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://redwebservermanager.redweb.network/DesktopService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDesktopService"
            contract="ManagerService.IDesktopService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IDesktopService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

If I manually set the credentials username and password everything works correctly however I have been trying

```
managerService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

so that I can pass the current users credentials over but I keep getting an error on the call to GetClients() that the username and password is not set.

Can anyone help me? I also tried adding

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
```

to the method but this made no difference.

Comment: I know it sounds silly, but have you tried **not setting** `ClientCredential` at all. We are using `NetTcpBinding` with transport security and the above works for us.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the Username (and more information other than the password) using one of the following ways:

```
//1. 
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
//2.    
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
    WindowsPrincipal user = (WindowsPrincipal)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
//3.    
WindowsIdentity ident = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    WindowsPrincipal user = new WindowsPrincipal(ident);
```

But, there is no way you can access the password of the user. Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949340/getting-networkcredential-for-current-user-c)

Once you receive the Identity information, you can pass the username to WCF using OutgoingMessageHeaders, like:

```
MessageHeader<string> header = new MessageHeader<string>(userName);
        OperationContextScope contextScope =   new OperationContextScope(InnerChannel);
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(
        header.GetUntypedHeader("String", "System"));
```

And in the WCF service implementation you can read it like:

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;

            if (context != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _LoginName = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<string>("String", "System");          
                }
                catch
                {
                    _LoginName = string.Empty;
                }
            }
```

Please let me know if this helps or if you have any other questions.

Thank you,
Soma.

Answer (score 5):

I feel like you can find your answer here: [Intranet - web to remote wcf CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010204/intranet-web-to-remote-wcf-credentialcache-defaultnetworkcredentials-not-worki). Basically you can't use Windows Authentication from Windows Forms application to WCF. You can only use it directly with WCF or Forms.